# orElse with in If then condition in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to manipulate following condition to check if value is either 41 or 42 then  ii want to exit the condition , any value other than 41 or 42 i want to execute SendEmailCPK(Msg).

Following is the code i have , but it's not working

```
If (rs.Fields("machine").Value <> "42" OrElse rs.Fields("machine").Value <> "41") Then 

    SendEmailCPK(Msg)

    EventLog1.WriteEntry(EventLog1.Source, "Coil " & rs.Fields("Lot").Value & " " & rs.Fields("Coil").Value & " Cpk is Out of Spec " & rs.Fields("cpk").Value)

End If
```

Comment: I think you want `AndAlso` instead of `OrElse`

Comment: You said in your text "if value is 41 or 42 then exit the condition" which isn't what you wrote in your code. instead you want "if value is not 41 and not 42 then do the condition"

Comment: Are the values always Numbers (Integers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values of rs.Fields("machine") are always numbers you could do

```
Dim machine as Int = CInt(rs.Fields("machine").Value)

If Not (machine >= 41 AndAlso machine <= 42) Then
   SendEmailCPK(Msg)

   EventLog1.WriteEntry(EventLog1.Source, "Coil " & rs.Fields("Lot").Value & " " & rs.Fields("Coil").Value & " Cpk is Out of Spec " & rs.Fields("cpk").Value)

End If
```

As mentioned by Matt below a neater solution which makes the code easier to understand is...

```
If (machine < 41 AndAlso machine > 42) Then....
```

Comment: I totally agree with you. However I think (as a personal opinion) that it is harder to understand at first glance...

Comment: Six of one and half a dozen of the other... both versions (as long as the field values are numeric) will work and are as confusing as each other... As in most programming there is more that one way of getting to an answer... that's where all the fun lies.

Comment: True to that... One other thing I just noticed : `CInt(rs.Fields("machine").Value)`

Comment: Martin,  It seem's to be working . Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I definitely think that condition should be rewritten without the `Not` so it is `If (machine < 41 AndAlso machine > 42) Then` otherwise it is pretty confusing

Comment: @MattWilko  and there is version 3!... and I must say more neater.

Answer (score 3):

You mean if value is different from 42 and from 41 ?

```
If (rs.Fields("machine").Value <> "42" AndAlso rs.Fields("machine").Value <> "41") Then 
    SendEmailCPK(Msg)
    EventLog1.WriteEntry(EventLog1.Source, "Coil " & rs.Fields("Lot").Value & " " & rs.Fields("Coil").Value & " Cpk is Out of Spec " & rs.Fields("cpk").Value)
End If
```

Comment: Martin,

Thanks for quick response , 

Value can't be either 41 or 42 , Both values wont exist at the same time , only on of these values will go under condition.

Comment: @MEngineer No. Martin´s answer is absolutely correct. If value does not equal 42 AND if value does not eqaul 41 you want the code inside to be executed. Please read a bit about [logical truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) to understand the difference between AND/OR in computer science and interpretation in human languages.

Comment: the orelse condition cannot work here because it will always evaluate to true if they are both in the system correct? AndElse if 42 is found do stuff. If 41 is found do stuff correct?